# IllegalMonitorStateException in a notify Entity Manager jpa resource

Tags: java, jpa

I want to check if my current transaction is not Active to performe a new one. I want to make this operations synchronized for a shared Entity Manager. So I used the approach wait() and notify() as below:

```
public static void getTransaction() throws Throwable {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        synchronized (em) {
            if (em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
                em.wait();
            }
        }
        return executeTransaction();
    }



public static void executeTransaction(){
     EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        synchronized (em) {
            EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
            tx.begin;
            //execute persist operations
            tx.commit();
            em.notify();
     }
}
```

But I receive this error in em.notify():

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: null
> at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)

Where is the mistake?

thanks

Comment: That is the exception thrown when a thread calls wait or notify on an object it doesn't hold the lock on.   Maybe the persistence calls not shown overwrite the contents of the  local variable em

Comment: How can i solve it? is not enought using synchronized  ? thanks

Comment: Not enough if the object you lock on gets swapped out. You lock on the object, not on the variable.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I Will appreciate more implementatations details...